# customize android google map direction line

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I had implemented [this](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/drawing-driving-route-directions-between-two-locations-using-google-directions-in-google-map-android-api-v2/) code for google map direction between two poin . 
now I want to customize this line between this two point . but I can't see any API or value for this work . how can I customize this line color , width , ....
thank you .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can customize line through `PolylineOptions` class which is already in code. Check below lines in `ParserTask`'s `onPostExecute` method:

```
            lineOptions.width(2);
            lineOptions.color(Color.RED);
```